# static dictionary does not get filled

Tags: c#

This is the working code:

```
    static class Global
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, int> emails_compsIDs;
        private static Dictionary<string, int> set_emails_compsIDs { set { emails_compsIDs = value; } }
        private static DataTable MultiCompReport;

    static Global()
    {
        string e = string.Empty;
        Dictionary<string, int> emails_compsIDs = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        DataTable t = MySql.ExecuteSelect("SELECT Email, Company_ID FROM potencial_contact WHERE Email != '' AND Email IS NOT NULL");

        foreach (DataRow r in t.Rows)
        {
            int comp_id = Convert.ToInt32(r["Company_ID"]);
            e = r["Email"].ToString().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim().ToLower().Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e) && !emails_compsIDs.ContainsKey(e))
            {
                try
                {
                    emails_compsIDs.Add(e, comp_id);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        if (emails_compsIDs.ContainsKey("linda@andatrade.com"))
            Console.WriteLine("Eureka");
        set_emails_compsIDs = emails_compsIDs;
    }
}
```

But, when I did just `emails_compsIDs = new Dictionary<string, int>();`
in order to initialize the dictionay in the constructor the code only filled the 1st row into it.
By creating an instance indise the ctor and then putting the result in my static dictionay it filled all the rows.

Comment: That try / catch is pointless and harmful, btw

Comment: its only there for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
Dictionary<string, int> emails_compsIDs = ...
```

Which declares a local variable rather than assigning a static field. It should just be:

```
emails_compsIDs = new ...
```

If that only fills one row, you should step through to find why.

Comment: The code block was checked without the local variable. It didn't work in the first place till the local variable was set there and hence the question.

Comment: @bresleveloper You probably had an exception before, perhaps from a null value in your DB?  That could cause either `o.ToString()` or `Convert.ToInt32(o)` to fail.

Comment: oh no, check my query, i filtered the null and empty. seems that the static ctor, which is not exactly a ctor and dont have the exact same behaviors like an instance ctor, was re-initializing the dictionay again and again.

Comment: @bresleveloper not from the code shown, it won't. But it would be easy to check with a breakpoint on the `new` line in the ctor

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in which I had declared a static dictionary in a non static class but was initializing the dictionary in the class constructor. This resulted in a new dictionary being created every time.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Icon> IconDict;

public FileOps()
        {
            IconDict = new Dictionary<string, Icon>();
        }
```

You need to initialize the dictionary in the declaration itself.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Icon> IconDict = new Dictionary<string, Icon>();
```